# R: Custom Function - Mutate Existing Column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'd like to create a custom function to try and standardise strings in multiple different columns, in multiple different data frames, with the ultimate intention of joining data from them together.

In order to do this, I'd like to be able to pass a column name into a custom function and have the function carry out operations on that column. With the example beneath, I'd like to clean columns *a* and *c* before joining them together to look like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(a = c("apple & pear", "kiwi", "plum"), b = c("cat", "dog", "cow"))
df2 <- tibble(c = c("apple and pear", "kiwi.", "plum"), d = c("car", "bike", "truck")) 

full_join(df1, df2, by = c("a" = "c") )

  a              b     d    
1 apple & pear   cat   car   
2 kiwi           dog   bike   
3 plum           cow   truck
```

Instead of how it currently turns out like, which is this:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  a              b     d
1 apple & pear   cat   NA   
2 kiwi           dog   NA   
3 plum           cow   truck
4 apple and pear NA    car  
5 kiwi.          NA    bike
```

To do this, I know I need to build custom functions, which I'd be relatively inexperienced at doing, especially with [curly-curly](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/02/glue-strings-and-tidy-eval/). The two functions beneath should change the symbols and remove the trailing punctuation, and ideally these should be combined into the one function, with the flexibility to be able to add more if necessary, like this:

```
add_symbol <- function(col.name){
  mutate({{col.name}} = gsub(" & ", " and ", {{col.name}}))
}

rm_trail_punc <- function(col.name){
  mutate({{col.name}} = gsub("[[:punct:]]$", "", {{col.name}}))
}

standardise_col <- function(df, col.name){
  df %>%
    add_symbol({{col.name}}) %>%
    rm_trail_punc({{col.name}})
}

df1 <- standardise_col(df1)
standardise_col(df2) %>%
  full_join(., df1, by = c("a" = "c"))
```

However, these functions can't be created, and return an error `unexpected '='` because the column name can't be passed to the left-hand side of the equal sign. Is there any way of passing these values to the `mutate` without hard-coding them?

Comment: please provide better sample data, you have df1 & df2 and then after the join you suddenly have Cat, Cow and dog in the dataset, and df2 appears nowhere

Comment: Apologies, changed it in the original code but didn't post things correctly here. Updated this now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve this more simply using with the following:

```
library(dplyr)

clean_func <- function(df){
    df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~gsub(" & ", " and ", .) %>% 
                    gsub("[[:punct:]]$", "", .))) 
    }

df1 <- clean_func(df1)
df2 <- clean_func(df2)
```

You can make updates to the function by adding additional `gsub`, `str_replace`, or other calls as needed.

Edit:

Based on update, you can do something like this to target your variables specifically:

```
add_symbol <- function(col.name){
  gsub(" & ", " and ", col.name)
}

rm_trail_punc <- function(col.name){
  gsub("[[:punct:]]$", "", col.name)
}

standardise_col <- function(df, col.name){
  
    col.name <- enquo(col.name)
    
  df %>% 
    mutate(!!col.name := add_symbol(!!col.name),
           !!col.name := rm_trail_punc(!!col.name))
}
```

Your code won't ever work as written, but you could do something like this:

```
new_df <- standardise_col(df1, a) %>% 
left_join(., standardise_col(df2, c), by = c("a"="c"))
```

Which gives us:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  a              b     d    
  <chr>          <chr> <chr>
1 apple and pear cat   car  
2 kiwi           dog   bike 
3 plum           cow   truck
```

You can read up on tidy evaluation here: https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/dplyr.html

Comment: Apologies for the bad data in the original question and thanks for the answer. Looking for something slightly more targeted though.

Comment: No worries - I added a new solution that will hopefully work for your purpose

Comment: Perfect, that does the job great. Actually had something similar before but didn't know about the `:=` operator.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment by @1k monkeys and a single PC, your example data are different from what you show, so maybe the results could be different, but let's assume you've some data like this:

```
df1 <- tibble(a = c("apple & pear", "kiwi", "plum"),
              b = c("cat","dog","cow")) 
df2 <- tibble(c = c("apple and pear", "kiwi.", "orange"),
              d = c("truck","bike","car"))
```

You can manage to use the package fuzzyjoin to merge them:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
stringdist_full_join(df2, by = c(a = "c") ,
                          max_dist = 3,
                          distance_col = "DIST")

# A tibble: 4 x 5
  a            b     c              d      DIST
  <chr>        <chr> <chr>          <chr> <dbl>
1 apple & pear cat   apple and pear truck     3
2 kiwi         dog   kiwi.          bike      1
3 plum         cow   <NA>           <NA>     NA
4 <NA>         <NA>  orange         car      NA
```

The result is different because I've based the data on your example and "plum" and "orange" doesn't match (so cow and car are not aligned). Clearly with a `select()` you can select the column you need, or with `mutate()` you can rename them.

Comment: Apologies about the data, updated it now. Thanks for the answer, but the string distance joins doesn't really work with the real-life use case because the size of the data makes it too long to manually de-duplicate the similar joins afterwards.